# MSVC - Creating a static library via Makefile

Tags: visual-c++, command-line, static-libraries, linker-errors, gnu-make

So I've been trying to create a static library under Windows under MSVC by launching mingw32-make under Microsoft's x64 Command Line Tools. I get linker error LNK1561: entry point must be defined. For completeness, here's my Makefile.

```
all: build\lib\libds.lib

build\lib\libds.lib: build\obj\priority-queue.obj
    link /OUT:build\bin\libds.lib build\obj\priority-queue.obj

build\obj\priority-queue.obj: libs/ds/priority-queue.c include/ds/priority-queue.h
    cl /Iinclude /c libs/ds/priority-queue.c /Fo:build\obj\priority-queue.obj
```

When I add a definition for main(), the library links without issue. What's the deal?

Comment: add `/lib` option to linker command line, like `link /lib /OUT:build\bin\libds.lib build\obj\priority-queue.obj`

Comment: Make it an answer so I can accept it. I found nothing on MSDN. MSDN does not list this information and it may be useful to others building on the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when we build static library we need use `link.exe /lib [LIB Options]` or `link.exe -lib [LIB Options]` or `lib [LIB Options]`. this is not well documented (partially here - [*Running LIB*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/running-lib))

note - that when you run `lib.exe xxx` - it exec `link.exe -lib xxx` and exit - so `lib.exe` not self-service utility but shim to `link.exe` (same as `dump.exe xxx` reexec `link.exe -dump xxx`). we of course can use `lib.exe` for build, but better use `link.exe /lib` command.